# Run T Test on Filtered Column in Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, statistics

I have a dataframe with 3 columns:
df=

```
+------+------+---+
| Var1 | Var2 | n |
+------+------+---+
| Y    | N    | 5 |
| Y    | Y    | 6 |
| Y    | N    | 3 |
| N    | Y    | 8 |
| N    | N    | 1 |
| N    | Y    | 9 |
+------+------+---+
```

I'd like to run a t-test for the values in n, on Y vs N in Var2, but only when Var1 = Y. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried `subset` i.e. `subset(df, Var1=='Y')` and then do the test on the subset data.  Perhaps `library(data.table);  setDT(df)[Var1=='Y', t.test(n[Var2=='N'], n[Var2=='Y'])$p.value]` (the example may not have enough observations)

Comment: That "works", but is there a way I can do it without creating a new dataframe first?

Comment: You could do `with(df[df$Var1 == "Y",], t.test(n[Var2 == "Y"], n[Var2 == "N"]))`

Comment: @Adam_G I only convert to `data.table` using `setDT`.  It should be efficient

Comment: Thanks for these. That works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), we set the logical condition `Var1=='Y'` to index the rows, subset 'n' elements where `Var2=='N'` and `Var2=='Y'` separately, and do the `t.test`.

```
  library(data.table)
   setDT(df)[Var1=='Y', t.test(n[Var2=='N'], n[Var2=='Y'])$p.value]
```